# Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document - javascript this keyword

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have the following code in my react  component

```
useEffect(() => {
    document
      .querySelector('#client-list > li')
      .addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (document.querySelector(this).index() === 0) {
          document.querySelector('.client-parent').removeClass('hidden');
          document.querySelector('.client-avatar-output').classList.add('mb-2');
        } else {
          document.querySelector('.client-parent').classList.add('hidden');
        }
      });
    }, []);

return (
  <ul id='client-list'>
    <li>Item1</li>
    <li>Item2</li>
  </ul>
)
```

for **this** keyword in line **document.querySelector(this).index** it throws the following error when list item is clicked.

> SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '[object
> HTMLLIElement]' is not a valid selector.

what am i doing wrong. any help will be greatly appreciated. thanks

Comment: `document.querySelector` needs a `DOMString` as argument, not an html element. Also, since you are using react, refrain from using DOM methods altogether - React will not find out you did this and rerender the elements when the component rerenders.

Comment: @Taxel can you please point out what to change in code

Comment: What exactly do you want to accomplish? I am reading it correctly that you want to modify the element that was rendered with React, right?

Comment: I want to replicate $(this) behaviour in `this` place

Comment: Please read up on [the basics of React](https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html) which contains how you add event listeners, and how React works in general. Stuff you rendered with React should NEVER by modified by DOM methods like `.classList.add` etc. since React might always overwrite your changes when it rerenders.

Answer (score 0):

change your `useEffect` like show below:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const ul = document.querySelector("#client-list");
    ul.childNodes.forEach((childNode, index) => {
    childNode.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       console.log(e);
       console.log(e.target === ul.childNodes[0]);
       if (e.target === ul.childNodes[0]) {
          document.querySelector(".client- 
        parent").classList.remove("hidden");
          document.querySelector(".client-avatar- 
         output").classList.add("mb-2");
       } else {
         document.querySelector(".client-parent").classList.add("hidden");
         }
      });
    });
   }, []);
```

Comment: dear, I'm sure. it does not replicates behaviour of `this` keyword